# addChild not displaying anything on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So I'm trying to make a spaceship fire lasers when the spacebar is pressed.  I've done this before in a pure flex project but have recently gotten creative cloud and am trying to recreate the same effect using flash professional/flash builder.

Unfortunately when I create a new instance of my "Laser" class and try and put it on the stage with addChild() nothing seems to happen.

Here is the main file/document class

```
    public class PlayerShip extends Sprite
    {

        private var laserTimer:Timer;
        private var shipTime:Timer;
        private var upKey:Boolean;
        private var downKey:Boolean;
        private var leftKey:Boolean;
        private var rightKey:Boolean;
        private var spacebar:Boolean;
        private var utils:Utils = new Utils();

        //tuning variables
        private var MOVE_SPEED:int = 5;
        private var REVERSE_SPEED:int = 3;
        private var TURN_SPEED:int = 5;

        private var laserEmitter:shipLasers = new shipLasers(stage);

        public function PlayerShip():void
        {
            super();

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fly);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, movementKeysDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, movementKeysUp);

            laserTimer = new Timer(1000/1000);
            laserTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fireLasers);
            laserTimer.start();
            addChild(laserEmitter);
        }

        public function fly(e:Event):void {
            if(downKey) {
                SpaceShip.x -= Math.sin(utils.degreesToRadians(SpaceShip.rotation)) * REVERSE_SPEED;
                SpaceShip.y += Math.cos(utils.degreesToRadians(SpaceShip.rotation)) * REVERSE_SPEED;
            }
            if(upKey) {
                SpaceShip.x += Math.sin(utils.degreesToRadians(SpaceShip.rotation)) * MOVE_SPEED;
                SpaceShip.y -= Math.cos(utils.degreesToRadians(SpaceShip.rotation)) * MOVE_SPEED;
            }
            if(leftKey) {
                SpaceShip.rotation -= TURN_SPEED;
            }
            if(rightKey) {
                SpaceShip.rotation += TURN_SPEED;
            }
        }

        public function movementKeysUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void { //rotators is key_up :P
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 83:
                    downKey = false;
                    break;
                case 65:
                    leftKey = false; // on "a" key_up sets left turn to false. Simple enough.
                    break;
                case 68:
                    rightKey = false; // K. "d" released makes me not turn right.
                    break;
                case 87:
                    upKey = false; // I guess case 87 is "w"
                    break;
                case 32:
                    spacebar = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public function movementKeysDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void { // key_down for movers
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 83:
                    downKey = true;
                    break;
                case 65:
                    leftKey = true; //so now on key_down for the "a" key it makes me go left! :D
                    break;
                case 68:
                    rightKey = true; //same as lft...
                    break;
                case 87:
                    upKey = true;
                    break;
                case 32:
                    spacebar = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public function fireLasers(e:TimerEvent) {
            if(spacebar) {
                laserEmitter.Emit(SpaceShip.x, SpaceShip.y, SpaceShip.rotation);
                addChild(laserEmitter);
            }
        }

        public function getShip():MovieClip {
            return SpaceShip;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the separate class that is supposed to create new instances of the Laser class and put them on the stage.

```
    public class shipLasers extends Sprite implements Emittable
    {
        var tempLaserRight:MovieClip;
        var tempLaserLeft:MovieClip;
        var laserArray:Array = [];

        public function shipLasers(stage:Stage):void
        {
        }


        public function Emit(x:int, y:int, rotation:Number):void {
                tempLaserRight = new Laser();
                tempLaserLeft = new Laser();

                tempLaserRight.rotation = tempLaserLeft.rotation = rotation;
                tempLaserRight.x = 200;
                tempLaserLeft.x = 210;
                tempLaserRight.y = 200;
                tempLaserLeft.y = 200;

                laserArray.push(tempLaserRight);
                laserArray.push(tempLaserLeft);
                stage.addChild(tempLaserRight);
                stage.addChild(tempLaserLeft);

                trace("Oh come on!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never store passed stage reference in `shipLasers` class, thus you are trying to refer its own built-in stage ref, which is likely null because your instances of `shipLasers` don't get added to display list themselves. You need to store the stage ref passed in the constructor and use that to add children.

```
 public class shipLasers ... {
     var theStage:Stage;
     public function shipLasers(aStage:Stage){
         theStage = aStage;
     }
     public function Emit(...) { 
         ...
         theStage.addChild(tempLaserRight);
         thestage.addChild(tempLaserLeft);
     }
 }
```

Update: It's also a good practice to first check stage availability, then use stage reference. To do this, you need to listen to `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event in your **ship** class, as it uses stage left right and center. The common code of achieving this is as follows:

```
public function PlayerShip() {
    ....
    // leave here only code that does not require stage 
    if (stage) init(); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
}
private function init(e:Event=null):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    // here place all code that's left from your initialization process
    laserEmitter=new shipLasers(stage);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, movementKeysDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, movementKeysUp);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I now have a stage variable taking the stage object passed in from the constructor, and am calling addChild from that new stage object as you've shown, but I still get nothing but a trace statement for some reason.

Comment: You have to trace more than just "Come on", say X and Y position for them lasers, their rotation, also after adding you are able to get `localToGlobal()` conversion for lasers' destination points. It's possible that your lasers are way out of visible part of stage.

Comment: Also, see updated answer for another possible error that prevents your game from working right.

Comment: I put in the init function in PlayerShip's constructor and traced the coordinates and rotation of the laser's and used localToGlobal and they are in fact showing up where I expect them to be (I checked another SO topic on proper use of localToGlobal so I think I'm using it correctly).

I have no idea if it could actually be a problem, but i've tried moving the background off the stage to make sure they aren't somehow behind it, and that's not the problem either.

Comment: Using `localToGlobal()` should be like `tempLaserRight.localToGlobal(new Point())`, the object calling `localToGlobal()` should be the one which position you need to determine. **DO NOT** use `this` or empty qualifier from within `shipLasers` class, you'll receive bogus values if you do this, because your `laserEmitter` is not the part of display list that contains those lasers.

Comment: Yeah that's how I've got it right now. I'm defining a var globalPoint:Point (probably unnecessary intermediary step) and then setting globalPoint = tempLaserRight.localToGlobal(new Point()) then tracing the globalPoint.x and .y respectively

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try not making lasers fire too fast, your timer is set for `1000/1000` that is 1, meaning 1 millisecond between triggering. Please set it to `(1000,1000)`, also check if your lasers have anything visible on the first frame. Perhaps lasers are there, but invisible.

Comment: So I did a visible check and it was visible.... Then I looked in the library and found the Laser class and saw that the window that shows images in flash pro was blank when I selected the Laser class.

I imported it by importing the png to the library and then dragging it onto the stage where I converted it to a symbol and then deleted the original png (because they had conflicting names and I didn't think I needed both) but apparently that's not how you import things.

So sorry for the big search for nothing, but you definitely helped me understand as3 better.

Also how should I close the Q?

Comment: You should see a "tick" outline on the left of any answer to your question. Select the one that helped you (or the one that's most appropriate) and click that "tick". The question will then be marked as "answered", you don't need to do anything further.